# inserting data to remote sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, yii

I have a following scenario. I have two web applications running on two different servers. I want to insert data from server1 webapplication to server2 sqlite database. [image]

As sqlite does not support remote connection I am looking for alternative ways to insert data like calling webservice, etc.

Any possible alternatives suggested is appriciated.

Thanks.

PS: both server has application developed in Yii+Apache(not sure this information is needed)

Answer (score 2):

This consists of 2 steps:

1. On the SQlite side, create a tiny PHP API, that accepts SQL to execute via a POST request. Do not forget to implement authorization!
2. On the main App (MySQL) side, make sure, you create SQlite-compatible SQL, then use cURL to post it to the SQlite side

As for authorization: A simple solution with a shared secret might be to

- on the MySQL side read the current timestamp
- - concatenate $timestamp.$sharedsecret.$sql
- - calculate a hash (SHA256 comes to mind)
- - Send timestamp, SQL and hash as POST parameters
- On the SQlite side
- - check the timestamp, fail if it is too old or new (replay security)
- - calculate hash($timestamp.$sharedsecret.$sql) and compare to sent hash, fail if wrong
- - run the SQL and give back result

This ofcourse assumes, that SQlite side fully trusts the MySQL side.

Comment: Thanks. This idea was in my mind of using curl. but I was worried about security. Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small API on server2 for handling updates/requests from server1. A RESTful API would be nice, creating sensible endpoints for your tables. Try and see [Toro](http://toroweb.org) for this or [Dispatch](http://noodlehaus.github.io/dispatch). You can then communicate to server2 using curl functions, or by using some HTTP client library like Guzzle.

If the frequency of updates that need to be sent over is high, then doing the message passing in the background might be a better approach. This would make your application handle more connections better and won't hold up your request handling with network requests. If this is the case, you can do this via cron jobs (not realtime), or even better, with Gearman.

For the server-to-server security concern, you can restrict access by:

1. using some form of basic authentication (request signing), or
2. by exposing server2's API to server1 via a private network, or
3. by whitelisting server1 on server2 (via your firewall or webserver).

Comment: Thanks for answer.However,In this aproach the updates may not be real time or I need to set up a cron job which checks every second which is not prefered..